# Filtering posts via users interests?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

So I have an app like twitter but I want to "wall" to have posts from all users but to be filtered by the current user's interests...

I want something like the following:

```
$posts = PostModel::with('interests')->latest()->get();
$user = UserModel::find(Auth::user()->id);

    foreach ($posts as $post) {

        foreach($user->interests as $interest){

           return only the posts that have the interest_id that matches
           the user's interest_ids

        }

    }
```

This is my UserModel interests function:

```
  public function interests() {

    return $this->belongsToMany('InterestModel', 'users_interests', 'user_id', 'interest_id')->withPivot('interest_id');
}
```

This is my PostModel interest function:

```
  public function interests() {

    return $this->belongsToMany("InterestModel", 'post_interest', 'post_id', 'interest_id');

}
```

I just can't figure out how I would sort and return the posts?

Thanks

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy method:

like $user->interests the corresponding $posts->interests is a Collection (http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html).

To check whether a Post has interest $interest, why not check whether it is in this collection:
$posts->interests->has($interest);

---

But in general looping in PHP has bad performance compared to SQL. So why not fetch only the matching posts in the first place?

```
$userInterests = UserModel::user_interest()->list('id');
$postWithInterest = PostModel::whereHas('post_interest', function($q)
{
    $q->whereIn('id', $userInterest);
})->get();
```

Although above code is untested, i hope it can show the basic idea.